# Image is not displaying

Tags: asp.net, image, path, src

i want to display the image in image tag in asp.net.

if the image is in project folder the image ll be display 
suppose the image path is in apart from project folder isn't display .
even though i need to it. Any can help me?

i tried following code it ll work
ie the image is in project floader

```
<img src="D:\New folder (4)\2014_images\AA10196.jpg" style="padding-left: 0px; border:0px; height: 60px;" alt="img not found" />
```

i tried this code isn't work
ie the image is in apart from project code

```
<img src="E:\New folder (4)\2014_images\AA10196.jpg" style="padding-left: 0px; border:0px; height: 60px;" alt="img not found" />
```

Comment: try this path      ../2014_images\AA10196.jpg

Comment: @DenishParvadia What is this. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

use ResolveUrl to get Absolute path

```
imgupload.Src = ResolveUrl("/2014_images/AA10196.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use HttpHandler .....

Create a HttpHandler getImage.ashx
Now on .aspx page

> 

And in getImage.ashx code behind

> using System; using System.Web;
>
> public class Handler : IHttpHandler {
>
> ```
> public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
> ```
>
> context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
>     context.Response.WriteFile("D:\New folder
>   (4)\"+context.Request.QueryString["file"]);
>       }
>
> ```
> public bool IsReusable {
> ```
>
> get {
>         return false;   }
>       } 
>   }